# How to make a surface dynamic in famo.us?

Tags: javascript, famo.us

I would like to change the text content of my famous surface based upon a global index, but the text isn't incrementing. How would i go by doing this?  Heres my code:

index = 0; is a global var that is incremented based on clicks on the surface

Slideshow.js

```
function _createBackground() {
    text = ['Hey', 'yo', '2']; 

    var background = new Surface({
        content: text[index],
        properties: {
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFF6',
            boxShadow: '0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
            cursor: 'pointer',         
        }
    });

    this.mainNode.add(background);

    background.on('click', function() {
        this._eventOutput.emit('click');
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Slideshowview.js

```
var index = 0;
SlideshowView.prototype.showCurrentSlide = function() {
    this.ready = false;

    var slide = this.slides[this.currentIndex];
    console.log(this.currentIndex);
    index = this.currentIndex;
    this.lightbox.show(slide, function() {
        this.ready = true;
        slide.fadeIn();
    }.bind(this));

};
```

Comment: Could you create a codepen with your problem so we can fork it and work on it. Difficult to answer your question when first having to setup a case myself.

Answer (score 0):

**This is taking a guess at your calling routines, but you need to scope index into your call.**

```js
function _createBackground(index) {
    text = ['Hey', 'yo', '2']; 

    var background = new Surface({
        content: text[index],
        properties: {
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFF6',
            boxShadow: '0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
            cursor: 'pointer',         
        }
    });

    this.mainNode.add(background);

    background.on('click', function() {
        this._eventOutput.emit('click');
    }.bind(this));
}
```

#### Make your background call as so

```js
_createBackground.call(this, index);
```